# Initial View Controller Title Changes to "Back" Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have no idea what's going on here. I have a single view application in a UINavigationController. The first page title starts out as one thing, but once you navigate 2 pages away, when you come back the title is just "Back".

Here's how page #1 looks when you first open the app:
[image]

Then when you click to page #2 (note the back button says "Main Page":
[image]

At this point, if you click the back button, the title of page #1 is still "Main Page". If instead you go to page #3, you see this (I set the title of page #2 to " ", so the back button is just an arrow):
[image]

When you hit the back arrow to return to page #2, the title of the back button has changed to "Back":
[image]

When you follow that back button to page #1, the title has changed to read "Back". Any further navigation that occurs doesn't change the title:
[image]

Here's any code that pertains to setting the title, the navigation bar, pushing viewcontrollers, anything I can think of that could possibly be related:

AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isOpaque = false
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
```

Page #1 view controller:

```
func launchContent(clerkship: String) {
        let listVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListViewController") as! ListTableViewController
        listVC.currentClerkship = clerkship
        navigationController?.pushViewController(listVC, animated: true)
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Main Page"
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.93, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0)
```

Page #2 viewcontroller:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let contentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
    contentVC.currentContent = contentDict[currentClerkship]![indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    contentVC.currentClerkship = currentClerkship
    navigationController?.pushViewController(contentVC, animated: true)
}
```

Page #3 Viewcontroller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = clerkshipToDisplay.darkColor
    self.title = contentToDisplay.title
```

I've tried restarting Xcode as well. Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I'm an idiot. Just found this embedded in my Page #3 viewDidLoad method. It must have been left over from when I was messing with the titles a few days ago and I missed it when I was checking for causes. If anyone else has this problem, here's the culprit:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Back"
```